# Search for multiple result between two patterns in a single string

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have an issue in parsing some data.

My file is as follows:

```
bliblablo-/interestingdata1UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU/-blublu-/interestingdata2UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU/-blybly-/etcetcetc
```

And I need to get:

```
interestingdata1
interestingdata2
```

When I had only one "interestingdata" like this:

```
bliblablo-/interestingdata1UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU/-bl
```

The following command worked for me:

```
cat file | sed -E 's/.*[-][/](.*)[U]{15}.*/\1/g'
```

However, it doesn't work anymore with multiple matching in the same string (it only prints the last match). 
My delimiters are always "-/" for the beginning and "UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU" for the end. **I don't know what's between those two but I need to extract everything**.

Does anybody know how to figure this out?

Comment: Why not use `grep`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro I think the problem here is that regular expressions are greedy, so if the `start ... end` pattern occurs repeatedly on the same line, _everything_ between the _first start_ and the _last end_ pattern will be matched.

Comment: I don't know how to use grep the way I want to. The problem here is that I don't know what i'm extracting (it could be written in chinese), the only information I have are the delimiters (-/ and 15*U).
About greedy regex, this is what I was suspecting being the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU grep in PCRE mode, with lookarounds and non-greedy matching:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=-/).*?(?=U{15})' file
interestingdata1
interestingdata2
```

Comment: Incredible, it finally works! Thanks a lot. I would never have figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example all you need is this which will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -F'([^/]+-|U{15})/' '{for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) print $i}' file
interestingdata1
interestingdata2
```

Comment: Hello Ed, sorry for the delay. Very interesting answer. Will definitely add that string to my bow (no pun intended).